# how to use array defined with angular in an jQuery code

Tags: jquery, angular

how can i use that array of image sources which i defined in the class of an angular component how to use it in jQuery is there any possible way
this is the code

```
 constructor() { }

 public publicImages = [
   "./../../../assets/data-image/cafe1.jpg",
   "./../../../assets/data-image/cafe2.jpg",
   "./../../../assets/data-image/cafe3.jpg",
   "./../../../assets/data-image/cafe4.jpg"
]

 ngOnInit() {
   $(function (){
   'use strict';


  for(let i=0; i < this.publicImages.length;) {
    $('.place-img').attr('src', this.publicImages[i]);
    i = i + 1;
  }
```

so what i'm trying to do is to bind this array to the view and use this array to know its length to make a next and previous buttons with jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making an old-styled JS function, so "this" does not refer your class.
You have to do it with arrow funtions :

```
ngOnInit() {
$(() => {
  'use strict';


  for(let i=0; i < this.publicImages.length; i++) {
    $('.place-img').attr('src', this.publicImages[i]);
  }
}
```

Or you may make a new variable which your function will see this way:

```
ngOnInit() {
let scopedPublicImages = this.publicImages;
$(function() {
  'use strict';


  for(let i=0; i < scopedPublicImages.length; i++) {
    $('.place-img').attr('src', scopedPublicImages[i]);
  }
}
```